# Error in a method that sequential searches

Tags: java, arrays, search

I'm trying to compare the year I want to find with the years that are in my array, and BlueJay is telling me "int cannot be dereferenced." Why?

About the error, BlueJay says "you are using dot notation to access a field or method of another object. However, the variable you are using is not of an object type - it does not have fields or methods." I think I understand this, but not sure what to do to fix.

The searchYear() method sequential searches to see if there are any CDs for a particular year; it should list all the CDs it finds. It has two arguments: the array and the year I want to find.

```
public static void searchYear(Music[] m, int toFind)
{
    int found = 0;
    System.out.println("Search results: ");
    for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        if (m[i].getYear().compareTo(toFind) == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(m[i]);
            found++;
        }
    if (found == 0)
    { //year was not found
        System.out.println(toFind + "is not in the music library");
    }
}
```

Here is my array:

```
    Music [] myMusic = new Music[10];
    myMusic[0] = new Music("Pieces of You", 1994, "Jewel");
    myMusic[1] = new Music("Jagged Little Pill", 1995, "Alanis Morissette");
    myMusic[2] = new Music("What If It's You", 1995, "Reba McEntire");
    myMusic[3] = new Music("Misunderstood", 2001, "Pink");
    myMusic[4] = new Music("Laundry Service", 2001, "Shakira");
    myMusic[5] = new Music("Taking the Long Way", 2006, "Dixie Chicks");
    myMusic[6] = new Music("Under My Skin", 2004, "Avril Lavigne");
    myMusic[7] = new Music("Let Go", 2002, "Avril Lavigne");
    myMusic[8] = new Music("Let It Go", 2007, "Tim McGraw");
    myMusic[9] = new Music("White Flaw", 2004, "Dido");
```

I need to tackle this error first, but with some more tweaking the results should eventually resemble these *sample outputs*:

Search - Year - 2001 
Search results: 
Misunderstood, 2001, Pink 
Laundry Service, 2001, Shakira 
There were 2 listings for 2001

Search - Year - 2003 
Search results: 
There were no listings for 2003

**Any and all assistance is much appreciated!**

Comment: Why not just do `m[i].getYear() == toFind`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because java's `int` are not objects, they are primitive types, so you cannot access to them with a dot (which is reserved for objects).

For more info about primitive types, go [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

So, if your function `getYear` retrieves an `int`, then you need to modify your if condition to `if(m[i].getYear() == toFind)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change 
    if (m[i].getYear().compareTo(toFind) == 0)

to

```
if (m[i].getYear() == toFind) {
```

What you're doing is call the compareTo method of the year field of the Music object at position m[i]. But if that year is an int that can't work. But you can compare ints directly by using ==